# How can i convert linq in queryable select?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this select new `LINQ` query :

```
 var listaClienti = from c in contestoDB.Clienti
                    where c.Cognome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) 
                       || c.Cognome == nominativoDaCercare 
                       || c.Cognome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare) 
                       || c.Nome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) 
                       || c.Nome == nominativoDaCercare 
                       || c.Nome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare)
                    select new 
                    {
                        IDCliente = c.ID,
                        Cliente = c.Nome + " " + c.Cognome,
                        Indirizzo = c.Indirizzo,
                        Telefono = c.Telefono,
                        CodiceFiscale = c.CodiceFiscale,
                        PartitaIva = c.PartitaIva,
                        NumeroVeicoli = f.CalcolaNumeroVeicoli(c.ID) 
                    };
```

How can i do it fast as this similar:

```
var elID = contestoDB.Clienti.AsQueryable().Select(n => n.Nome, c => c.Cognome) ?? null;
```

Comment: Can you explain better what exactly you want? I don't understand your question

Comment: Well, first thing I see is that you have four superfluous conditions there.  "c.Cognome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Cognome == nominativoDaCercare || c.Cognome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Nome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Nome == nominativoDaCercare || c.Nome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare)" is the same as "c.Cognome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Nome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare)".  The reason is that if it equals or starts with it, then it will contain it as it hits that condition first.  The || short circuits it so it'll return at the first true condition.

Comment: 1:  Those two queries do different things, with the second query having no filter at all.  2:  The first query has 3 checks on the same column against the same value and then another 3 checks on the other column, again with the same value which seems fairly useless as they're all `OR` conditions.

Comment: And you don't give any metrics, so what is "fast"?

Comment: `?? null`? "If it's null [which it can't be] then return null instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly need.
But maybe it is something like this?

```
var listaClienti=contestoDB.Clienti.AsQueryable()
.Where(c=>c.Cognome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Cognome == nominativoDaCercare || c.Cognome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Nome.Contains(nominativoDaCercare) || c.Nome == nominativoDaCercare || c.Nome.StartsWith(nominativoDaCercare))
.Select(c=>new
    {
        IDCliente = c.ID,
            Cliente = c.Nome + " " + c.Cognome,
            Indirizzo = c.Indirizzo,
            Telefono = c.Telefono,
            CodiceFiscale = c.CodiceFiscale,
            PartitaIva = c.PartitaIva,
            NumeroVeicoli = f.CalcolaNumeroVeicoli(c.ID)
    });
```